# Open source or free antivirus software

Tags: antivirus

Can you kindly tell me regarding antivirus software, open source or free codes are safe or not? If safe, how is it possible as there are so many antivirus companies, giving the same by taking a bit of money?

Answer (score 2):

> For the most part, Linux is engineered in a fashion that makes it hard
>   for viruses to run. However, there are many reasons you might want a
>   virus scanner on your Linux PC:
>
> 1. to scan a Windows drive in your PC
> 2. to scan a Windows-based network attached server or hard drive
> 3. to scan Windows machines over a network
> 4. to scan files you are going to send to other people
> 5. to scan e-mail you are going to forward to other people
> 6. some Windows viruses can run with Wine.
> 7. Linux virus infections are theoretically possible.<sup>1</sup>

For full detailed information [Visit Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Documentations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your question is related to Ubuntu, the fact is that this operating system is a lot less prone to virus attacks than others, in particular because the vulnerabilities are rapidly fixed by the frequent updates, and because most administrative procedures are protected by a password.

If you want to install a free open-source antivirus, one of the most renowned for linux is **ClamAV**, and you can get it with a user interface buy installing **ClamTk** in the software centre.